# I need to group by one column and show more columns from one dataset

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following table:

```
AMNT1   |  COLUMN1  |  COLUMN2  |  COLUMN3    | GROUP1
--------|-----------|-----------|-------------|--------
1.00    | COL1_ROW1 | COL2_ROW1 |   COL3_ROW1 | AAA
9.00    | COL1_ROW2 | COL2_ROW2 |   COL2_ROW2 | AAA
2.00    | COL1_ROW3 | COL2_ROW3 |   COL3_ROW3 | BBB
3.00    | COL1_ROW4 | COL2_ROW4 |   COL3_ROW4 | CCC
```

I want to sum AMNT1 grouped by GROUP1:

```
SELECT GROUP1, SUM(AMNT1) FROM ND_TEST GROUP BY GROUP1;

GROUP1 | SUM(AMNT1)
-------|-----------
AAA    | 10.00
BBB    | 2.00
CCC    | 3.00
```

Addtionally I want to select COLUMN1, COLUMN2 and COLUMN3 from ONE row. So my output should be like this:

```
GROUP1 | SUM(AMNT1)|  COLUMN1  |  COLUMN2  |   COLUMN3  |
-------|-----------|-----------|-----------|------------|
AAA    | 10.00     | COL1_ROW1 | COL2_ROW1 |  COL3_ROW1 |
BBB    | 2.00      | COL1_ROW3 | COL2_ROW3 |  COL3_ROW3 |   
CCC    | 3.00      | COL1_ROW4 | COL2_ROW4 |  COL3_ROW4 |
```

If I use sum over partition I get duplicates per group... If I use aggregate functions, I dont get result from the same row...
Do you have an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: What you show is selecting "from ONE row" - a single row is not a dataset. Then - in the case of group AAA, **which** row do you want to select? Why the first row, and not the second? (Or do you need to just select one row at random, when there's more than one row in a group?)

Comment: It doesnt matter which row. The only thing important is that all columns come from the same row...

Comment: If it doesn't matter what row are from the other columns, why not use `MAX()` function  on each column?

Comment: I wont get the result from the same row with MAX...

Comment: Yup... just say that... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select group1, sum_amnt1, column1, column2, column3
from   (
         select group1, sum(amnt1) over (partition by group1) as sum_amnt1, 
                column1, column2, column3,
                row_number() over (partition by group1 order by null) as rn
         from   your_table
       )
where  rn = 1
```

`order by null` in the `row_number()` function corresponds to your clarification (in a Comment) that **any** row from each group will be fine (you don't care which one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select nt.*
from (select nt.*, sum(AMNT1) over (partition by GROUP1) as sum,
             row_number() over (partition by GROUP1 order by AMNT1) as seq
      from ND_TEST as nt
     ) nt
where seq = 1;
```